# Writing list in one row csv in r

Tags: r

I have a list of lists and I want to write every list to one row in csv, separated by commas. The list of lists is called `Winkelmandjes`. It looks like this:

```
[727]]
 [1] "taart"                      "mini slagroom en marsepein" "taart"                      "taart"                     
 [5] "taart"                      "taart"                      "karrewiel"                  "pistolet"                  
 [9] "pistolet"                   "pistolet"                   "pistolet"                  

[[728]]
[1] "brood"      "marsepein"  "koffiekoek" "taart"      "hoorn"      "koffiekoek"

[[729]]
[1] "koffiekoek"          "brood"               "gv-lv tompoes (2st)"

[[730]]
[1] "brood"              "wit vierkant klein" "koffiekoek"         "koffiekoek"         "brood"             
[6] "koffiekoek"         "koffiekoek"        

[[731]]
[1] "taart"      "koffiekoek" "taart"      "taart"
```

I have tried to loop with lapply over `Winkelmandjes` but this didn't work. I also don't succeed in creating a data frame of `Winkelmandjes`. I know this has to do with the fact that the rows don't have the same length, but I can't find a solution for this.

```
lapply(Winkelmandjes, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'test.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))
```

I would like to create a data frame or create a csv file with the different values per list in one row. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to create a data.frame or matrix by fillling with NA for length that are shorter `dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst1)))); write.csv(dat, "file.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your list into a vector of comma-separated strings, then write them to file:

```
strings = sapply(lst1, paste, collapse = ",")
writeLines(strings, con = "myfile.csv")
```